# How to initialize Application Context on load with Jersey 1.8?

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I'm using Java 1.7, Spring Framework 3.1 and Jersey 1.8.

I created a simple class `TeamData`

Through `localhost:8080/team/{id}` I can receive a team name with id = {id} from my DB.

```
@Path("team/")
public class TeamData {

@GET
@Path("{id}")
public Response getTeamById(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    TeamServiceImpl teamServiceBean = getTeamServiceBean();
    Team team = teamServiceBean.getTeamById(id);
    output = "Team name : " + team.getTeamName();
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}


/**
* Method gets bean from ApplicationContext
*/
public TeamServiceImpl getTeamServiceBean() {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "bean-spring.xml");
    TeamServiceImpl teamServiceBean = (TeamServiceImpl) applicationContext
            .getBean("teamService", TeamServiceImpl.class);
    return teamServiceBean;
    }

}
```

> How to initialize Application Context on loads?

Is there a way to do something like in Servlets?

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private ApplicationContext ac;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean-spring.xml");
    }

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          // TODO:
          }

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create the context yourself. Just use the [`jersey-spring`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-spring) integration module. Let Jersey create and maintain it for you.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

You should be able to `@Autowired` your services in your Jersey resource classes with no problem. Of course there is some configurations required.

Here are some complete example resources to go off of:

- [Complete example from Jersey project](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/tree/master/samples/spring-annotations)
- [Mkyong: Jersey + Spring integration example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/)